# How i can call a function every hour even when the app is in background - Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, background-process

I want to call a function that will make a post request. That function should be called every hour . How exactly do I to call the function every hour even when the app is on background?

I'm doing the app in cordova and only for android

Comment: You could use a `timeout` or `interval` but the time-interval will likely not be consistent. "Timers such as setTimeout() are throttled in background/inactive tabs to help improve performance.", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API . So you might want to consider a web worker, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin : **cordova-plugin-background**

and in index use this code for refrech the app every hour

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

             cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

               setInterval(function () {

                  YourFunctionHere();

                }, 3600000);
             }
           }, false);
```

your app it' well refrech in backround every hour

> 3600000 millisecond = 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

### Backgrounds services

Every new version of Android brings restrictions on background processing, because it uses RAM and battery and drain the resources from the phone. In the past, there was a lot of apps running all kind of background processes, resulting in very poor battery life. Since Android 5/6, there is a clear push toward ending "do-what-you-want-when-you-want" background processing.

See the official docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

### What you can do

As such, you never know when your app process will be paused or killed to free up resources. Using pure Javascript methods won't get you far because if the app process is stopped, the Javascript code cannot run.

#### Rethink your app design

Do you really need to check on your server every hour?

#### Use a custom plugin

See the docs and implement the background process with native code. For that, you might need to create your own Cordova plugin. Take a look at how they're made (like the [ionic-plugin-deeplink plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks)), and check the [Cordova reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html).
Notes : To add a local plugin to your app, just use the following code (no need to publish it to npm if you don't want to or can't)

```
cordova plugin add ./path/to/my/custom_plugins/cordova-plugin-my-background-process
```

#### Use Push notifications?

Just an idea, but you might even get around that problem by sending push notifications every hour, and have your app do its work in response to that notification?